# Is there any way to check the security setting of a Chrome browser?

Tags: javascript, security, google-chrome, https

I want to access some code from an http:// source from an https:// website. I have a popup that prompts  the user to change their security setting but I don't want the popup to show every time I go to the homepage of the site. Is there any way to check their Google Chrome browser settings to indicate if they already enabled the insecure elements to show?

Currently I have:

```
function alertLoadData() {
    var is_chrome = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf('chrome') > -1;
    var secure = isSecure();
    if (is_chrome && secure) {
    alert('Please click on the shield to the right of the address bar to show the contents of the site. NOTE: the contents come from an insecure http:// address.');
    }
}
```

Where `isSecure()` checks that they are in the https:// part of the website. I want something like: `alreadyEnabledSecurity()` which checks whether the user has already enabled the insecure contents to show and if so:

```
function alertLoadData() {
    var is_chrome = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf('chrome') > -1;
    var secure = isSecure();
    var settings = alreadyEnabledSecurity();
    if (is_chrome && secure && !settings) {
    alert('Please click on the shield to the right of the address bar to show the contents of the site. NOTE: the contents come from an insecure http:// address.');
    }
}
```

Comment: There is really little point in making your site HTTPS, if you're going to serve insecure content on it. You punch a gaping hole in your secure site for hackers to attack it. You should remove the SSL from your main site or not serve insecure content, and then you don't have worry about it.

Comment: Perhaps you could use cURL or some such to retrieve this problematic HTTP content from wherever it comes from, server-side, then deliver it to the user over HTTPS.